estimating category thresholds across a continuous variable using Ordered logistic regression
I've got a set of tomatoes at various stages of ripening, with as an ordered categorical variable ["green","yellow", "orange","red"], along with their weight as a continuous variable. I want to estimate between which weights my tomato is most likely to be of a certain color, and if the range of weights in which my tomatoes are most likely to be green (or yellow, or red) is wider than each other color's most likely interval.
For this, I've been using ordered logistic regression to obtain the thresholds between the categories, followed with a bootstrapping procedure in order to have an estimate of the confidence that I could put in the model.
Is this appropriate ? Is there a better way ?
Now harder : I've got a second tomato variety. I want to see if it follows the same ripening pattern, or if some specific stages are proportionally longer or shorter in the second variety. Is there a cleaner way than, again, bootstrapping ?
In case it can change the way you answer, I'm using the vglm package in R for this.
Here is some toy data :
structure(list(color = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 
1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 
4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 
2, 2, 4, 4), weight = c(8.87461456154191, 9.74158314824944, 7.80981466931723, 
4.15519793301398, 8.0414251436767, 5.3925766439293, 0.798763535858539, 
5.05131527741666, 1.30460282068467, 2.36471422759222, 9.06493163940618, 
5.91573097870244, 0.192807184547038, 4.8268754473533, 2.25924325252297, 
7.94531990507251, 2.68211552197479, 1.61885439793218, 1.10636785013358, 
1.64810356280911, 1.73359732214988, 8.12232519673807, 3.52417894993908, 
5.67017647934931, 6.18494464896992, 8.44993434445183, 2.21842741762134, 
2.20959885016432, 0.577180395960791, 8.32239255536373, 8.79946775015629, 
8.3832931592299, 0.0249011679023806, 2.17876346348318, 2.71321765909802, 
6.7133249095566, 0.400755720508472, 7.87275532735968, 5.14268050516384, 
8.74578152254024, 1.86031046594665, 9.16038819918548, 2.87892922491477, 
0.494662566522184, 5.22837614220193, 3.72972362909342, 3.68067174710088, 
9.13841758668379, 4.66152558569492, 9.48932486513245, 8.34224298574605, 
3.14783906882033, 1.95955443528089, 5.39227581091657, 9.8507431534492, 
0.323611480137518, 0.675719129304016, 7.65702829088943, 7.96139764733576, 
4.68358838499317, 6.29552602368599, 6.70287806431587, 3.77689889592958, 
2.95833005782494, 4.85727964327327, 5.94146733542076, 0.0207658461962897, 
3.45582325703901, 7.31031086342853, 5.11456758499018, 5.60618384146289, 
4.50738592998656, 1.7023046679675, 3.50012639180617, 1.81734523783897, 
4.48283144974202, 0.56761815557436, 8.93686414347044, 8.03628073474192, 
3.1795893327346, 1.25461694404004, 1.69049180404963, 8.00253320536444, 
5.75336129376964, 3.3204166465118, 4.56186253945971, 0.756083513267312, 
8.55079571448138, 6.0717140657282, 7.59992467526412, 9.1854982129258, 
5.35207882935426, 8.19061298709136, 1.53843086340472, 0.928504601275767, 
6.5098290500278, 2.67500434454591, 0.713549494290284, 8.13156071322409, 
7.50780697798306)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")

And results obtained from it :
first, a single generation using the whole dataset
Call:
vglm(formula = ordered(color) ~ weight, family = propodds(reverse = T), 
    data = samples)

    Coefficients: 
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept):1  -9.2875     1.6354  -5.679 1.35e-08 ***
    (Intercept):2 -10.8882     1.8489  -5.889 3.88e-09 ***
    (Intercept):3 -14.5297     2.3177  -6.269 3.63e-10 ***
    weight          2.1577     0.3452   6.250 4.10e-10 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Names of linear predictors: logitlink(P[Y>=2]), logitlink(P[Y>=3]), logitlink(P[Y>=4])
    
    Residual deviance: 88.5841 on 296 degrees of freedom
    
    Log-likelihood: -44.292 on 296 degrees of freedom
    
    Number of Fisher scoring iterations: 9 
    
    Warning: Hauck-Donner effect detected in the following estimate(s):
    '(Intercept):1', 'weight'
    
    
    Exponentiated coefficients:
      weight 
    8.651256 

the parallel assumption testing (using default VGLM parameters) outputs this :
(Intercept)      weight 
      FALSE        TRUE 

(btw it's out of scope but I'm not sure how to interpret this output)
and finally the graph I obtain with the bootstrap procedure. In grey, the true bounds coming from data generation, colors show model, error bars correspond to threshold position confidence intervals, and dots to data points


Looks okay, but maybe you can show us some of your data, plots, or some model fits? Little more to say without ...

Added some info !

up, just in case
